# Is rainy weather in Minecraft dark enough to spawn monsters?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it dark enough to spawn monsters, or bright enough to make them despawn?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**No.** Rainy weather reduces day-time light-levels to 12 at mid-day, which is [not low enough to spawn monsters](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Light#Effects_of_light). This 3-point decrease does mean that, as twilight falls, it will be darker sooner and monsters will spawn just that bit earlier—but of course, it's not "day" anymore at that point.

**However!** Thunderstorms have a light level of 7 at mid-day, meaning that monsters *will* spawn then. That's just one more reason to not go walking around when lightning is crashing down.

Comment: Well this helps because im in hardcore and all my survival worlds mobs spawn in rain

Comment: A very good answer, since it describes not only when darkness does take effect mechanically, but specifies that thunderstorms are even darker than regular rain, which I did not even know!

Answer (score 10):

Notch said on twitter:

> MUOAHAHA! Thunder Storms lower the brightness. That means daytime monsters during storms. This is freakily atmospheric.

https://twitter.com/notch/status/57363403102105600

So that means monsters will spawn during a storm (thunder and lightning) in the day, but not when it is only raining.

Comment: Also, monsters only burn in complete sunlight (rain decreases the light level by one I believe), so the monsters won't burn up.

Answer (score 0):

They can spawn in rain. I know because on my current world it is raining (but there is no thunder or lightning) and hostile mobs are spawning.

Comment: Are you under a lot of trees? That will make it darker.